# Updating/Inserting tables in one database from another database

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I sync two databases and do a manual refresh on the entities on either of the database whenever I want?

Let's say I have two databases `DB1(prod)` and `DB2(dev)`. I want to update/insert only a few tables from prod DB to dev DB. How could I achieve this? Is this possible instead of `DBlink` since I do not have privileges to create a database link?

Comment: If you can't have a DB link created, and assuming you have at least read access to the tables in the production database, there are a few ways I can think of to do this: 1) extract production data to CSV file,  copy text file to development, attach CSV file as external table, copy external table data to "real" table; 2) attach to production database using spreadsheet program, read data from production DB into spreadsheet, attach to dev DB, insert data from spreadsheet to dev DB; 3) use the export/import capabilities of you IDE (SQL Developer, etc). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do a manual refresh set up an import/export/datapump script to copy the data across if there is not too much data involved. If there is a large amount of data you could write some pl/sql as described above to only move the new/changed rows. This will be easier if your data has fields such as created/updated_on